# container view calls parent func in swift

Tags: swift2

In the storyBoard "parent" scene with its parentVC.swift, there is a containerView with embedded segue with its containerVC.swift.
I am able to call containerView.myFunc() in the  parentVC viewDidLoad() with no problems.
How can I call a custom func defined in parentView from an action of a button in containerView.

```
self.parentViewController.myCustomFunc()
```

I get

> Value of type UIViewController? has no member myCustomFunc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `parentViewController` so the compiler knows which functions are available.  The definition is simply `UIViewController?` which, as the error says, doesn't have your function.

Try:

```
if let vc = self.parentViewController as? parentVC {
    vc.myCustomFunc()
}
```

Comment: I tried to cast it before I ask but did not work,  (self.parentViewController as? ViewController)?.myCustomFunc(). but now is working :)